# Match values from two separate datasets into a single dataset

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a two files.

One is a json document and the other is a list of tuples.

The list of tuples contains ID numbers for all of the pairs.

In the json document, all of those ID numbers appear as the value inside of each dictionary row. So these can be gotten at:

```
id_list = []
for line in list_of_dicts:
    user = line.get('user')
        id = user.get('id')
        id_list.append(id)
```

Also in the json document is a name that goes with each ID number. These can be gotten at:

```
name_list = []
for line in list_of_dicts:
    user = line.get('user')
        name = user.get('name')
        name_list.append(name)
```

How can I put the names in these lists and match them as dictionaries with the ID numbers in the list of tuples?

Comment: `dict(zip(id_list,name_list))` ?

Answer (score 0):

If both of them are equal sized list then use dict with zip i.e

```
dict(zip(id_list,name_list))
```

Example

```
x = [1,2,3]
y= [4,5,6]
dict(zip(x,y))

{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
```